# Push docker image with devops to private azure container registry

Tags: azure-devops, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-registry

So I have a private Azure container registry, which by its nature also sites on a private VNET (it has to).

I have configured my private container registry to:

```
"Allow trusted Microsoft services to access this container registry"
```

I have also in my VENT allow Microsoft Container registry as a service endpoint.

However, when I push my image in devops with the below code:

```
  variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'myacr'
  imageRepository: 'my-image-repo'
  containerRegistry: 'myacr.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
 steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Login to ACR
  inputs:
    command: login
    containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build image with arguments
  inputs:
    command: build
    arguments: --build-arg git_personal_token=MYTOKEN
    repository: $(imageRepository)
    dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
    containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
    tags: |
      $(tag)
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: push the image
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
    repository: $(imageRepository)
    command: push
    tags: |
      $(tag)
```

I get the error:

```
denied: client with IP '51.145.2.107' is not allowed access. Refer https://aka.ms/acr/firewall to grant access.
```

However, I cannot set an IP address in the firewall, as the builder IP changes with each unique build that is generated. I thought I had allowed all microsoft services the correct access, have I missed something, or how can I debug this further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an Azure Container Registry where you have disabled public network access you will not be able to access it from a [Microsoft Hosted Azure Devops Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

The [Trusted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/allow-access-trusted-services#trusted-services) currently only contains a handful of service currently, but more may be added in the future:

> - Azure Container Instances
> - Microsoft Defender for Cloud
> - ACR Tasks
> - Machine Learning
> - Azure Container Registry

However it is not likely that Azure DevOps (at least not the agents) will be added, since Microsoft has no control over what code executes in them (an thus they are not trusted). The same principle applies for the [Azure DevOps service tag](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-devops-service-tag-released/), which do not include the Microsoft Hosted agents.

If you really need your registry to be fully private, you will need to use a [self hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) deployed in your own network that has access to the registry.

Comment: Thank you, so if I want to use devops and azure container registries, I must allow public access to my container registry, in light of this, how can this be an accepted commercial solution, seems really "unsafe"? (I may have misunderstood the term public in regards to the ACR?)

Comment: With "public" access I mean that the registry is accessible on an IP that is routeable on the (public) internet. The registry can still require authentication to access it. Think of it as an apartment building with an entrance door and one door for each apartment. The apartment doors are private endpoints not accessible to the public (you need to be inside the building first), but they still require a key to open. The entrance door on the other hand, is accessible to anyone on the street )i.e a public endpoint), but only people with the key can enter.

Comment: On your remark how a publicly routeable endpoint (that still requires authentication) is acceptable in a commercial solution: It is not acceptable in every solution. Sometimes it is, sometimes not, it depends on how risk tolerant you are and how you value perimeter security (the IP filters) vs identity security (the authentication). However, if you cannot tolerate public endpoints, then you need self hosted agents. After all the MS hosted agents are a shared environment, so even if you could allow them access to your registry, it would diminish the value of the firewall/private endpoint.